# How to logout and then re authenticate an anonymous firebase user

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

Users get loggedIn to my firebase app as anonymous users as soon as they start entering data. When ever they want, they can convert it to a normal account. To do that, I use FirebaseUI. Everything works well except when they aboard the signIn process. FirebaseUI automatically logout out the anonymous user at the beginning of the signIn process. Therefore they can't access their data anymore and I haven't found a way to re authenticate the anonymous user. Is there a way to store the credentials of the anonymous user and then re authenticate it?

Answer (score 2):

When you use anonymous users with Firebase Authentication, their identification is stored only on the device. When you sign out this user, their identification is removed from the device. There is no way to recover this identification once it is removed.

Comment: Yes, I know. But what is stored in the end is just a idToken and I can get that beforehand. I just can't log in with it again. I tried to use a customToken, but then the user isn't anonymous any more...

Comment: This is not true Frank. When you signin the user anonymously, information is also stored in firebase console.

Comment: OP asked how to re-sign in as the same anonymous user, which is not possible. While their UID may be stored on the Google servers, the necessary credentials to sign them into the same profile again are not stored (as far as I know).